# Получить сумму значений в столбце строчного типа SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу получить сумму всех значений колонки строчного типа? Для колонки числового типа я использовал функцию SUM(имя колонки) и мне вывело сумму значений в колонке, но для строчного типа эта функция не подходит. Думаю, нужно привести сначала значение колонки в тип числа и потом использовать эту функцию, но как это сделать не знаю. Или может есть другие варианты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, например так:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(field_name AS DECIMAL)) FROM table_name;
```

или упрощенная запись:

```
SELECT SUM(field_name::DECIMAL) FROM table_name;
```

Comment: а если как обычный интеджер, это будет NUMBER вместо Decimal?

Comment: @Vadym Так как я не знаю, какого вида у Вас числа, какого диапазона, я привел общий пример, как использовать конструкцию CAST (изменение типа). Если Вы заглянете вот сюда: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html, то увидите список возможных числовых типов данных. Выберите тот, что подходит под Ваш диапазон и в него и переводите. Для целых - integer, bigint, smallint в зависимости от диапазона.